# PHP waiting for API response

Tags: php, api, sockets

I am facing problem with API. I have my API, iOs app and foreign API.

iOs makes request on my API, my API makes request to foreign API. But now I have to wait for foreign API to send data to my callback which takes some time, for example 30 sec. How should I keep conenction with iOs app?

I have 3 possible solutions.

1. Ask my API for example every 10 sec. if data already arrived.
2. Send notifications to my app when data arrive.
3. Create socket which will listen for response, if I understand sockets correctly.

Is there any other solution? Or what is the best practice?

Comment: What protocols are you using? HTTP? Do you maintain a connection (e.g. TCP) between your app and the API?

Comment: I am using HTTPS. I do not maintain connection. Is there any article about how to implement connection between API written in PHP and iOS app?

Comment: I believe @Igor T. 's solution is ideal. Using sockets for this purpose is not very reliable, especially if the phone receives a call or goes to sleep, the socket connection will be lost. Querying the API every 10 seconds *could* be a fine solution if the user base is extremely small; however, this option is suboptimal as there will be many unnecessary queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach you could try is using APN for notifying the app about new data arrivals.

1. The iOS client makes a request to your API
2. Your API makes a request to the ext. API, returns a response to the iOS client
3. Once the data from the ext. API arrives, your API sends a push notification to the iOS client, notifying the latter that the data is ready to be picked up
4. iOS client receives the push notification (PN), does not show the PN to the user (human)
5. iOS client makes another request to retrieve the data.

Comment: Depending on the data you might be able to send it in the payload of the push notification. The payload size is now up to 4096 bytes according to official documentation. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html

Comment: If the way @chasenyc suggests works for you, it will save you an additional request time from paragraph 5, as you won't need to make it anymore.

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses, You suggested best solution for me. Will try it implement like this.
@chasenyc unfortunately it will be more than 4 kB, so iOs app has to make another request.